# ICS not working after reboot

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm on the latest version of Windows 10. I'm using my huawei E3272 to share Mobile connection to the router. This works great until I reboot my computer. Sharing option is still checked, but sharing is not working. I checked services - it seems that all of required by ICS are working. The rourer connection just say "No connection access". Then I uncheck and check again sharing option on Mobile connection - it works great again. Best solution at this moment would be to use some restart ICS script. I found https://github.com/utapyngo/[icsmanager](https://github.com/utapyngo/icsmanager) but unfortunately sometimes it throws Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException exactly like in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072135/programmatically-enable-and-disable-ics-internet-connection-sharing-in-windows
I posted this issue some time ago on Microsoft support site, i don't know if they're going to fix this or no. Maybe someone also had this issue and resolved it?

Comment: Have you ran the icsmanager script as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I ran icsmanager with admin rights.

Comment: Have you tried alternatives? Try using [kingron/wifi](https://github.com/kingron/wifi)

Comment: Oh, I noticed that LAUNCHING ICS is working on kingron/wifi and icsmanager. The problem is when it want to disable sharing. I'm trying to analize what is wrong.

Comment: You could always manually disable sharing via ncpa.cpl and selecting your network interface.

Comment: @AdamMańkowski, have you solved the problem? I got this issue too.

Comment: @Suncatcher no, it's still there even after windows reinstall

Answer (score 3):

An optional “EnableRebootPersistConnection” registry key was introduced in [KB4054517](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4054517/windows-10-update-kb4054517) (included in 1709). Setting this key to `1` (see below) and the ICS service startup type to "Automatic" fixes the issue for me.

A quote from [KB4055559](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4055559/ics-doesn-t-work-after-computer-or-service-restart-on-windows-10):

> To fix this issue, set the following registry subkey:
>
> Path:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedAccess
>   Type: DWORD Setting: EnableRebootPersistConnection Value: 1
>
> Then, change the ICS Service Startup mode to Automatic.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10 Pro v1909 even though that knowledge base article only mentions it applying to three specific older versions.  Also, a good sanity check to ensure ICS is configured properly by Windows is to check that the adapter you're sharing _with_ has a `192.168.137.1` address.  I had ICS enabled but hadn't used it in over a year, though I still expected connecting a device would "just work" (because why not?).  This must be one of those things that magically gets reset by feature updates.  I had to disable and re-enable ICS on that adapter for it to work again.